# How to select on the elsif when the email is a duplicate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an issue of when a email is a duplicate that it should have it's own custom pop-up via javascript. I use @emailexists to do this but the problem I'm having on the elseif I don't know how to specify the problem that it's actually a duplicate and thats the reason to use the elsif rather than else. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def create
  @ambassador = Ambassador.new(ambassador_params)
  if @ambassador.save
    puts "========================"
    puts "Successful Save"
    puts "========================"
    # redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Thank you for signing up!'
  elsif @ambassador.errors
    @emailexists = @ambassador.errors.full_messages
  else
    @errors = @ambassador.errors.full_messages
  end
end
```

Comment: Btw, I would strongly recommend using the rails logger instead of puts. The logger messages all appear in line with eachother synchronized, so that messages appear in the order and position they are sent. Puts will immediately write to the console, but it will likely end up disconnected from the rest of the log messages (such as active record messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably more straightforward here to explicitly check for an existing account using the same email, rather than allowing an error and trying to detect a specific error scenario from the errors.

```
def create
  @ambassador = Ambassador.find_by_email(ambassador_params[:email].downcase)
  if @ambassador
    @emailexists = true
  else
    @ambassador = Ambassador.new(ambassador_params)
    if @ambassador.save
      puts "========================"
      puts "Successful Save"
      puts "========================"
      # redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Thank you for signing up!'
    else
      @errors = @ambassador.errors.full_messages
    end
  end
end
```

Note that you'll also want to make sure that the Ambassador model downcases email addresses before save, in order to simplify subsequent existence checks.

```
class Ambassador < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  # Not all database adapters use case-sensitive indices,
  # so this helps ensure uniqueness no matter what.
  before_save { email.downcase! }
end
```

Comment: Per Paul's advice, you should definitely get familiar with using `logger.info "Successful Save"` instead of `puts "Successful Save"` -- the output will appear in `log/environment_name.log`. Docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html